# Docker Logstash, Failed to fetch pipeline configuration

Tags: windows, docker, logstash

On my windows machine i run this docker compose file:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  logstash:
    image: logstash:latest
    command: -f ./etc/logstash/config/ --log.level debug
    volumes:
      - ./config/:/etc/logstash/config/
      - ./pipeline/:/etc/logstash/pipeline/
```

logstash.yml:

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
path.config: /etc/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
path.settings: /etc/logstash/config/logstash.yml
```

This gives the error:

```
Failed to fetch pipeline configuration {:message=>"No config files found: ./etc/logstash/config/. Can you make sure this path is a logstash config file?"}
```

What can be the problem? This is my directory structure on my Win10 machine:

```
/docker
  /config
    /logstash.yml
  /pipeline
    /logstash.conf
```

-- Edit

Problem solved with the next config file:

`logstash:
    image: logstash:latest
    command: -f ./etc/logstash/pipeline/
    volumes:
      - ./config/:/etc/logstash/config/
      - ./pipeline/:/etc/logstash/pipeline/`

Comment: Where is `docker-compose.yaml` located? It looks like the folder with a config is not mounted to a container.

Comment: Its located in the ./config folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined to mount `./config` folder of the host machine to `/etc/logstash/config/` inside container according to the part of your `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
volumes:
  - ./config/:/etc/logstash/config/
```

The `./config` folder path on the host machine is relative path to the location of `docker-compose.yaml` file.

The `docker-compose.yaml` is located in `./docker/config` folder, so there is no `.config` folder inside it.

To achieve what you want just move `docker-compose.yaml` file to one level up:

```
mv docker-compose.yaml ../
```

File should be located inside `./docker` folder:

```
/docker
  docker-compose.yaml
  /config
    /logstash.yml
  /pipeline
    /logstash.conf
```

Comment: Thanks! Its solved now. Also the -f path was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You are mounting to wrong image directory. 
Logstas docker Image directory layout is as follows:

- /usr/share/logstash/config
- /usr/share/logstash/pipeline

and like this for bin, data etc.

Refer it for more: [Logstash Docker Directory Layout](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/dir-layout.html)

Comment: Same problem `No config files found: /usr/share/logstash/config. Can you make sure this path is a logstash config file?"`